# Repeating values - Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba, macros

I am provided a large spreadsheet monthly that requires up to 6 instances of the same customer ID to be entered manually. I would like to design a Macro or VBA code that will take my customer list and create a a series of repeating values on separate rows. For instance, column A currently contains the following:

```
     A
1  Cust1
2  Cust2
3  Cust3
```

My VBA/Macro would generate the following output:

```
     A
1   Cust1
2   Cust1
3   Cust1
4   Cust1
5   Cust1
6   Cust1
7   Cust2
8   Cust2
9   Cust2
10  Cust2
11  Cust2
12  Cust2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please feel free to design your rmacros/script. When you have done so come back to us with any problems you are having. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, try *searching* this site ([SU]).  Excel is a very popular topic here, and questions similar to yours have been answered before.

Answer (score 0):

With a Macro using VBA:

```
Public Sub customCustomers()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sourceSheet = "Sheet1"
    destSheet = "Sheet2"
    initialSrcRow = 1
    initialDstRow = 1
    times = 6
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks, wks1 As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets(sourceSheet)
    Set wks1 = wkb.Sheets(destSheet)
    wks1.Rows.Clear
    seeking = True
    While seeking
        theCustomer = wks.Cells(initialSrcRow, 1)
        If theCustomer <> "" Then
            For i = 1 To times
                wks1.Cells(initialDstRow, 1) = theCustomer
                initialDstRow = initialDstRow + 1
            Next i
            initialSrcRow = initialSrcRow + 1
        Else
            seeking = False
        End If
    Wend
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    theMessage = MsgBox("Finished copying customers on Sheet: " & destSheet, vbOKOnly)
End Sub
```

Open VBA/Macros, under *ThisWorkbook* insert a new module and paste this code on the right side.

You can adjust the following variables to suit to your needs:

- `sourceSheet`:   The name of the original sheet, in my example is
  *Sheet1*.
- `destSheet`: Name of the destination sheet, in my example is
  *Sheet2*.
- `initialSrcRow` : The first row on the source Sheet.
- `initialDstRow`: First row on the destination Sheet.
- `times`: Number of times the customer must be repeated on the
  destination Sheet.